# SNMP ping support for IPv6 address

Tags: ping, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

Whether "SNMP ping" is supported for IPv6 address ? Also whether latest NET-SNMP library provides support for "SNMP ping" .
RFC 4560 talks about snmp ping but it doesn't mention anything about IPv6 address.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4560

Thanks
-Ravi

Answer (score 0):

pingCtlTargetAddressType is of type InetAddressType which allows ipv6.